# Is it possible to pass a styled value of a variable in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

EDIT: Without using v-html as we have an eslint no-v-html

Is it possible to show something like "The community is here to help you with specific strong text **coding, algorithm, or language problems** " using data in vue?

Code is something like this:

```
<template>
 {{ description }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data() {
    return {
     description: 'The community is here to help you with specific strong text <strong> coding, algorithm, or language problems </strong>
 }
}

</script>
```

Comment: I assume it doesn't work? Do you get any errors in your browser console? Maybe close the string with a `'` first?

Comment: Hi, Simply enclose it in `<div v-html="description"><div>`

Comment: It works but it shows the strong tag. I basically get The community is here to help you with specific <strong text coding, algorithm, or language problems </strong

Comment: For this specific use case, `v-html` is the best solution, so you should disable that ESLint rule for this component.

Answer (score 2):

Yeap,
just use

```
<div v-html="description"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any other way? Our code base has eslint with no v-html

Comment: You can use vanila JS with getElementById and innerHtml

Comment: You can use   <!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html --> and   <!-- eslint-enable vue/no-v-html --> comments inside your template. Also make sure to sanitize the content as v-html is vulnerable to XSS attacks https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div id="description"></div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  mounted() {
    document.getElementById('description').innerHTML = 'The community is here to help you with specific strong text <strong> coding, algorithm, or language problems </strong>'
  }
};
</script>
```